# Similarity between two samples (2D matrices)

Tags: correlation, matrix, descriptive-statistics, cross-correlation

I have two matrices: 
A= 4000x78 where 78 is the dimension of features and 4000 is the number of samples.
B= 1000x78 where 78 is the dimension of features and 1000 is the number of samples again.

Now, I want to see how the two samples are related based on their feature values. More specifically, I want to see how many samples in A are similar to each of the 1000 samples in B.

Apart from simple similarity (in terms of distance functions between each of the samples in A and B), can I use any other metrics (like correlation statistics) to understand the relationship between both?

Comment: Check their principal components. If they are from the same population they should be fairly similar.  Also I think you are misleading potential readers with your title. You might attract a better crowd if you ask for 'similarity between two samples'.

Comment: I have reformatted the dimension of the matrices (in statistics we normally place the instance as rows and the measurements as columns)

Comment: You could aggregate the samples together and use a clustering algorithm. The makeup of the clusters will then tell you which of the samples in B are similar to those in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the *modified RV coefficient*. This is a kind of correlation coefficient for matrices. See:

Smilde, A. K., Kiers, H. A. L., Bijlsma, S., Rubingh, C. M., & van Erk, M. J. (2009).
Matrix correlations for high-dimensional data: the modified RV-coefficient. Bioinformatics,
25(3), 401–405.